# $W = \lbrace p \in \Pi_{5}(\Omega) : p'(−1) + p' (1) = 0 \rbrace $. Prove that $W$ is a subspace of $Π_5(\Omega)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm a bit stuck on this question. So if i'm not mistaken in order to prove that $W$ is a subspace of $\Pi_{5}(\Omega)$. I need to show that: $\textit{(i)}$ the zero vector is an element of $W$; $\textit{(ii)}$ $W$ is closed under addition and $\textit{(iii)}$ $W$ is closed under multiplication. (i'm not sure if i'm saying it right, so please correct me if i'm wrong).

[image]

$\textbf{(i):}$
$$p(x) = 0\;(\mathrm{zero\;vector}) = 0 + 0x + 0 x^2 + 0x^3 + 0x^4 + 0x^5 = 0$$
$$p'(x) = 0 + 2x0 + 3x^{2}0 + 4x^{3}0 + 5x^{4}0 = 0$$ 
$$p'(1) = 0$$ 
$$p'(-1) = 0$$ 
$$p'(1) + p'(-1) = 0 + 0 = 0$$ 
so i assume this proves zero vector is an element of $W$.

$\textbf{(ii):}$

Let $p,q \in \Pi_{5}(\Omega)$

I assume that i need to prove $(p+g)'(1) + (p+g)'(-1) = 0$, but how do i do that?

$\textbf{(iii):}$

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, and $p \in \Pi_{5}(\Omega)$. I need to prove $(\lambda p)'(-1) + (\lambda p)'(1) = 0$. I also am not sure how to do this.

I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: For (ii), $p,q \in \Pi_5(\Omega)$ so try and express $(p+q)'(1) + (p+q)'(-1)$ in a more convenient way. What does $(p+q)'(1)$ mean in this case?

Comment: im not sure... @B.Mehta

Comment: is it (p+q)'(x) = p'(x) + q'(x) ??

Comment: Yes! What can you do from here

Comment: do i differentiate the 5 degree polynomial for p and q, so p'(x) = p1 + 2xp2 e.c.t and same for q(x) then and them together to get (p+q)'(x), then sub in x = 1 the add that answer to the answer when x = -1?

Comment: wait actually can i just do (p+q)'(1) + (p+q)'(-1) = p'(1) + p'(-1) + q'(1) + q'(-1) = 0+ 0 = 0???

Comment: Yes, Jane, you can. It is justified.

Comment: Exactly, good work

Comment: Now something similar works out for the third part as well.

Comment: is it that (λp)′(−1)+(λp)′(1) = λ(p'(1) + p(-1)) = λ(0) = 0 ? Seems to simple so im not sure if it correct?? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: @Jane It is that simple. Of course, you are right.

Comment: thank you so much guys!